# Reading external file using javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, browser, request

Is it possible to read the m3u8 file(or any other text file for example) from an external source via http request of ajax?
And not using server side(such as node.js or c#) to request the file.
The file is sitting in http : // ... / file.m3u8
Thank you:)

Comment: if you can open it in a browser using the url, yes

Comment: And if there is no CORS issues

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this would help but I used this myself [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

You can use a GET request which will get the external document.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use an XMLHttpRequest to read files local to your Javascript, for example:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('get', '../file.m3u8', false);
request.send();
console.log('file contents: ' + request.responseText);
```

Full details on XMLHttpRequest on the [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) website.